# static_layer gets deleted by obstacle_layer in global_costmap

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, costmap-2d, global-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Previously (i.e. pre-hydro) it has been possible to have a `global_costmap` that takes in sensor data as well as the static map from the `map_server`. If I remember correctly, this  allowed to have the sensor data "clear" data of the static map to plan through, e.g., doors that had been closed during mapping.

With the current system, I haven't been able to reproduce this behaviour.
Even stranger: as soon as I add an `obstacle_layer` to the `global_costmap` (even without receiving any data on the configured sensor), the `global_costmap` simply doesn't receive any data at all. I.e. the robot plans the direct path to the goal, through whatever is set in the `map_server`.

I'm not sure if this is a configuration issue on my end, or if this is really something that is not possible with the layered costmap approach. Even if the "clearing" behaviour is hard to realize, my current system should end up with an "overlay" of the single layers. I.e. the `static_layer` should still show. This is also how I understand [this paper](http://wustl.probablydavid.com/publications/IROS2014.pdf) by @David Lu.

I created a minimal example (see below). This example is stand-alone and doesn't depend on Gazebo or a robot.

Any hint to where I have made a mistake would be highly appreciated!

---

**Results**

The trick was really the `combination_method` parameter in combination with the `track_unknown_space` parameter.

(Note: I used some fake laser which simply published a circle with radius 3m at 1° angular resolution. Also, the images only show the `robot_footprint` and the resulting `global_costmap`)

- I: The behaviour I experienced. `static_layer` gets completely overwritten by `obstacle_layer`
- II: behaviour I wanted. `static_layer` gets only overwritten by `obstacle_layer` where there are actually some measurements (see the light blue traces along the rays. It is not free space, but you see the effect). If you plan a path, it tries to follow any observations, if possible, and only cross unkown space if required (leads to some zigzag behaviour along the rays of the scans)
- III: default behaviour: obstacles present in either `static_layer` or `obstacle_layer` are used
- IV: afair, same as III for the costmap, though planning will happen as in II.

Below some pictures of the different combinations:

I: `combination_method: 0`, `track_unkown_space: false`
[image: image description]
II: `combination_method: 0`, `track_unkown_space: true`
[image: image description]
III: `combination_method: 1`, `track_unkown_space: false`
[image: image description]
IV: `combination_method: 1`, `track_unkown_space: true`
[image: image description]

---

***Minimal Example***

Put the following files in your home. You'll need a map to pass to the `map_server` as well as `rviz` with a proper configuration (`map`, `global_costmap`, maybe `robot_footprint`).

Play around with using the `obstacle_layer` in the `global_costmap` to see the different results.

`movebase.launch`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <!-- delete old parameters -->
  <rosparam command="delete" param="/move_base"/>

  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="/PATH/TO/MAP"/>
  
  <node name="map_to_odom" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" args="2 0 0 0 0 0 map odom 10"/>
  <node name="odom_to_base_link" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 odom base_link 10"/>

  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <param name="controller_frequency" value="10"/>

    <!-- Use the dwa local planner for the PR2 -->
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS" />
  
    <!-- Set the global_planner -->
    <param name="base_global_planner" value="global_planner/GlobalPlanner" />

    <rosparam file="./local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap"/>
    <rosparam file="./global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

`global_costmap_params.yaml`

```
global_frame: map # default: "/map"
robot_base_frame: base_link # default: "base_link"
update_frequency: 4.0 # default: 5.0
publish_frequency: 1.0 # default: 0.0
rolling_window: false # default: false
static_map: true # default: true

transform_tolerance: 0.6 # default: 0.2
footprint: [[0.35,0.205],[0.42,0],[0.35,-0.205],[-0.225,-0.205],[-0.225,0.205]]
footprint_padding: 0.01 # default 0.01

plugins:
- {name: static_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"} 
- {name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
- {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

static_layer:
  unknown_cost_value: 0 # default: 0
  lethal_cost_threshold: 100 # default: 100
  map_topic: map # default: "map"

obstacle_layer:
  combination_method: 0
  observation_sources: laser_scan
  map_type: costmap
  unknown_threshold: 2 # default: ~<name>/z_voxels
  mark_threshold: 0 # default: 0
  publish_voxel_map: true
  obstacle_range: 10.0                  # default: 2.5  
  raytrace_range: 10.0                  # default: 3.0 
  laser_scan:
    sensor_frame: laser                 # default: ""
    topic: /scan               # default: source_name
    data_type: LaserScan                # default: "PointCloud"
    marking: true                       # default: true
    clearing: true                      # default: false

inflation_layer:
  inflation_radius: 0.45 # default: 0.55
  cost_scaling_factor: 8.01 # default: 10.0
```

`local_costmap_params.yaml`

```
global_frame: map # default: "/map" -> WARNING: Default value has a "/" in front of the frame-name
robot_base_frame: base_link # default: "base_link"
update_frequency: 4.0 # default: 5.0
publish_frequency: 2.0 # default: 0.0
rolling_window: true # default: false
static_map: false # default: true

width: 5.0          # default: 10
height: 5.0         # default: 10
resolution: 0.05    # default: 0.05
origin_x: 0.0       # default: 0.0
origin_y: 0.0       # default: 0.0

transform_tolerance: 0.6 # default: 0.2
footprint: [[0.35,0.205],[0.42,0],[0.35,-0.205],[-0.225,-0.205],[-0.225,0.205]]
footprint_padding: 0.01 # default 0.01

plugins: 
- {name: obstacle_layer, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
- {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

static_layer:
  unknown_cost_value: 0 # default: 0
  lethal_cost_threshold: 100 # default: 100
  map_topic: map # default: "map"

obstacle_layer:
  combination_method: 0
  observation_sources: laser_scan
  map_type: costmap
  unknown_threshold: 2 # default: ~<name>/z_voxels
  mark_threshold: 0 # default: 0
  publish_voxel_map: true
  obstacle_range: 10.0                  # default: 2.5  
  raytrace_range: 10.0                  # default: 3.0 
  laser_scan:
    sensor_frame: laser                 # default: ""
    topic: /scan               # default: source_name
    data_type: LaserScan                # default: "PointCloud"
    marking: true                       # default: true
    clearing: true                      # default: false

inflation_layer:
  inflation_radius: 0.45 # default: 0.55
  cost_scaling_factor: 8.01 # default: 10.0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316191/static_layer-gets-deleted-by-obstacle_layer-in-global_costmap/) by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 12390 on 2019-02-20

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not able to run your example at the moment, but it is very helpful that you provided it.

The key parameter here is [combination_method](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/melodic-devel/costmap_2d/cfg/ObstaclePlugin.cfg#L11). You have it set to 0, which means overwrite. This means that whatever data is in the obstacle layer will be written into the master costmap, regardless of what is already in the master from the static costmap.

Try setting it to 1 for Maximum, which will combine the values.

Alternatively, you can set `track_unknown_space` to true so that only the values which your obstacle layer has marked as clear/occupied will be copied over.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2019-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-02-22**:
great! Thanks @David Lu I really missed that I actually set this parameter. I guess that `combination_method=1` seems to be the default then.

I'll update my question with some insights after testing this!

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-02-22**:
@David Lu as the `combination_method` parameter hasn't been documented, I took the liberty of [adding it to the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/costmap_2d/hydro/obstacles?action=diff&rev2=10&rev1=9) If you feel this is incorrect, please adapt or let me know. Thanks!

**Comment by [geoporus](https://answers.ros.org/users/57112/geoporus/) on 2021-04-08**:
thanks a lot for all the info and answers you have guys posted in this thread!